# ¿como mostrar la hora en pantalla sin salto de linea y catalogar ip?

Tags: c++

tengo dos problemas en mi código el primero que es el mas fácil que estoy usando en c++ la funcion `system("time /T");`
pero quiero poner que me ingrese una ip pero no quiero que me aparezca con un salto de linea sino que al contrario me aparecesca la entrada cin>>IP; sin salto de linea despues de  `system("time /T");` sino que por ejemplo

07:55 p. m. [100]

y el segundo es que quiero hacer cinco variables que me cuenten cuantas ips de clase a,b,c,d,e hay en el arreglo pero cuando lo ago en mi codigo no funciona y la logica del codigo esta bien pero no se porque no me imprime los valores

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void aleatory_ip(long ip,string IPs[],string IPc[],long i1,long i2,long i3,long i4,long i5){

     volatile int n1[ip];
     volatile int n2[ip];
     volatile int n3[ip];
     volatile int n4[ip];


     int j  = 0;
     int k  = 0;

     string IPa[ip]; 

      for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){  

        n1[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;
        n2[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;
        n3[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;
        n4[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;

      }    
      for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){       
       
       IPs[i] = to_string(n1[i]) + '.' +
                to_string(n2[i]) + '.' + 
                to_string(n3[i]) + '.' + 
                to_string(n4[i]) ;

       }


      for (int i = 0; i <ip; ++i){
    
       (n1[i]>=0   and n1[i]<=127) ? IPc[i]="A":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
       (n1[i]>=128 and n1[i]<=191) ? IPc[i]="B":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
       (n1[i]>=192 and n1[i]<=233) ? IPc[i]="C":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
       (n1[i]>=224 and n1[i]<=239) ? IPc[i]="D":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
       (n1[i]>=240 and n1[i]<=255) ? IPc[i]="E":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
                
       }         
      for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){

                  if (IPs[i] =="127.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="0.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="3.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="15.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="56.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="10.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="192.168.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="172.16.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="100.64.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else{ 
                   IPa[j] = IPs[i];
                   j++;
                 }
               }


                 for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){

                    IPs[i] = IPa[i];

                   }

                    j = 0;
                    k = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < ip; i++){
    
              for(j = i + 1; j < ip; j++){
    
                if(IPs[i] == IPs[j]){
     
                     k = j;
     
                     while(k < ip -1){
    
                        IPs[k] = IPs[k+1]; 
     
                        ++k;
                    }
     
                    --ip;
                    --j;
     
                
                  }
     
                }
     
             }
  for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){

    if (IPc[i] == "A"){

      i1++;

     }else if (IPc[i] == "B"){

      i2++;

     }else if (IPc[i] == "C"){

      i3++;

     }
    else if (IPc[i] == "D"){

      i4++;

     }
    else if (IPc[i] == "E"){

      i5++;

     }else{

      continue;

     }

   }

      
      cout<<"complete";
      cout<<".";
      Sleep(1000);
      cout<<".";
      Sleep(1000);
      cout<<"."<<endl;             
 }
void test_case(){

   system("color 6");
   system("time /T");
   
   long IP;
   cin>>IP;
 
   string IPS[IP];
   string IPC[IP];
 
   unsigned long i1 = 0;
   unsigned long i2 = 0;
   unsigned long i3 = 0;
   unsigned long i4 = 0;
   unsigned long i5 = 0;
  
   aleatory_ip(IP,IPS,IPC,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5);

  for (int i = 0; i < IP; ++i){

    cout<<"["<<i+1<<"]"<<"["<<IPC[i]<<"]"<<"["<<IPS[i]<<"]"<<endl;

   }

  cout<<"[A]"<<i1<<endl;
  cout<<"[B]"<<i2<<endl;
  cout<<"[C]"<<i3<<endl;
  cout<<"[D]"<<i4<<endl;
  cout<<"[E]"<<i5<<endl;

 }
```

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido pasar la variables i1-i5 como parametro porque solo pasaras su valor y no su direccion de memoria, lo que significa que no las vas a poder cambiar dentro de la funcion, mejor has que el argumento sea un puntero y le pasas todas las direcciones de memoria de esas variables: `void prototipo( long* i1,...,long* i5 );`. Desde text_case: `prototipo(&i1,...,&i5);`.

Comment: O mejor aun usa una matris de 5 elemennto: `long i[5];`, y pasas su longitud: `void prototipo(unsigned int longitud_i,long* i);`, desde text_case: `prototipo(5,i);`